# Is it possible to have a specific org-mode file use a custom theme or face?

Tags: emacs, themes, org-mode

I would like to be able to specify a theme or set of custom faces that are specific to a file that will be opened in `org-mode`. Is there any way I can do that? I already have https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local but that doesn't provide a way to automatically apply it when a specific file opens.

An ideal solution would not involve hardcoding in my init.el, but would involve setting a variable or calling elisp in the loaded file (or a referenced setupfile).

For an example of why this would be useful, some files are very flat, and are more readable with one set of styles, and other files are deeply nested, and benefit from another set of styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original poster has cited a particular library called `color-theme-buffer-local` ( https://github.com/vic/color-theme-buffer-local ), which the original poster wants to apply to a file opened in the major-mode known as `org-mode` -- only if a certain variable is `t`.

The following example uses the code cited in the instructions for `color-theme-buffer-local` by calling the line of code:  `(load-theme-buffer-local 'misterioso (current-buffer))`  The variable `my-favorite-variable` will control when the previous line of code is called when opening an `org-mode` buffer -- i.e., when `non-nil` it applies, when `nil` it does not apply.

---

**EDIT** (November 16, 2014):  The following is a revised answer based upon the desire of the original poster to use file-local variables:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html#File-Local-Variables

The behavior described by the original poster in the comment underneath this answer is due to the fact that the regular `org-mode-hook` is run **before** the file-local variables are taken into consideration.  Therefore, the variable `my-favorite-variable` was still `nil` when the `org-mode-hook` ran its course (using the initial answer).  The following revised answer uses the `hack-local-variables-hook`, which runs **after** the file-local variables are taken into consideration.

```lisp
(defvar my-favorite-variable nil)

(defun my-favorite-function ()
(interactive)
  (when
      (with-current-buffer (current-buffer)
        my-favorite-variable)
    (load-theme-buffer-local 'misterioso (current-buffer))))

(add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook 'my-favorite-function)
```

Comment: I tested `(load-theme-buffer-local 'misterioso (current-buffer))` in the buffer with `C-c C-e` and the theme changed. To test your code, I executed it in the scratch buffer, and put `# -*- my-favorite-variable: 1; -*-` in my org file, closed it with `C-x k`, and reopened it. The theme didn't change. `M-: my-favorite-variable` showed that it does have a value of 1. Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Thank you for teaching me about file-local variables and for helping me to learn that the standard major-mode hooks run **before** file-local variables are taken into consideration.  I've posted a revised answer that uses the `hack-local-variables-hook`, which runs **after** the file-local variables are taken into consideration.

Comment: Hmmm! You're welcome :). Good sleuthing, though I'm not wedded to using file local variables - I just want to be able to set something in the file somehow (and ideally in a setup file) which controls the theme. This now works in the file, but it turns out file local variables aren't great in org-mode and don't work in setup files. So I'm now looking for other ways (perhaps org-mode file tags)?

Comment: Additional ideas may be to include a set of choices when the file opens -- e.g., (1) do X; (2) do Y; (3) do Z -- if not 1, 2 or 3 and a set number of seconds elapse (e.g., 10 seconds), then choose the default option (whatever that is).  Another idea would be to create a particular file extension (using the `auto-mode-alist` and a custom function) that loads one type of theme, and another extension that loads a different theme -- e.g. file-name.org1 file-name.org2.  A third idea may be to have a speed-dial -- load theme number 1, 2 or 3 theme -- or a function on speed-dial that offers 1, 2 or 3

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, color themes are global, for the whole Emacs session running. The same applies for background color which I'd like dark for shell buffers, and light otherwise; not possible ATM.

If you like light backgrounds, you can have a look at my color theme "Leuven" (in Emacs 24.4, in MELPA or on GitHub) and report improvements you'd find useful.

Comment: The library cited by the original poster uses the `face-remapping-alist`, which is what is used to make faces buffer local.  Can you please add a compare and contrast statement in your answer that explains the difference between your statement that color themes are global in general, verses the exception to the rule when using the `face-remapping-alist`:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Remapping.html

Comment: Thanks fniessen for creating Leuven. I'm actually asking this question because your theme is perfect for some of my documents (more nested documents) but very bad for others (which are mostly shallow todo lists - solarized for example is much better for those).